# Entering Password Automatically for Stripe From Bash Script

Tags: bash, curl, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's Curl API to create subscriptions.

My bash script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

set pass MyPasword123
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2 -d card[number]=4242424242424242 -d card[exp_month]=12 -d card[exp_year]=2016 -d card[cvc]=123 -d plan=EarlyAdopter -d email=test@gmail.com
expect -re "Enter host password for user 'sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2:':"
send "${pass}\r"
```

This does now work.

How do I enter automatically a password for the Stripe Curl API?

Thanks...

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean by that? Is there an error message? Nothing comes through?

Comment: Also, if you are in bash, then you can't just `send` your password. You need to be in Expect for that.

Comment: `curl` isn't going to prompt you for credentials in a way that `bash` or `expect` can handle. This is entirely the wrong approach here. You also, as chrisaycock indicated are confusing `bash` and `expect` here a bit.

Answer (score 11):

The issue here is that you are only passing the API key but you're missing the `:` at the end. This is mentioned in the documentation about the [Authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#authentication). It should be like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers    \
   -u sk_test_XXX:                          \
   -d card[number]=4242424242424242         \
   -d card[exp_month]=12                    \
   -d card[exp_year]=2016                   \
   -d card[cvc]=123                         \
   -d plan=EarlyAdopter                     \
   -d email=test@gmail.com
```

Comment: True, inasmuch as this is an error, but also sidestepping the question (the answer to which would call for something like `-u sk_test_XXX:"$pass"`, as awful as that is from a security-practice perspective).

Comment: ...though one could use `curl -K` / `curl --config` to read a password from a file, which can be less insecure than using the command line (given exposure of command-line arguments to other processes on the system); that might be a worthy addition as well.

Comment: But there's no password on Stripe's endoints though, you use your Secret API key `sk_XXX` as a username and no password which is why he gets his issue and why my answers tells him how to fix it. I didn't address the whole "how do I send a password to curl" here since it's not really what's blocking him

Comment: Ahhhh. That explains things; the question, then, is whether the API key itself is secret enough to want to keep it out of the process table.